# Limiting view of index, but allowing edit in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-2.0

So I want to hide a certain view from people that aren't logged in, and want to allow a certain user role to edit/delete, etc.

But using Auth->allow and isAuthorized is a tad confusing. Is there a way to simplify the following?

I want to allow a certain roles (coach and admin) to see index and view, and completely hide them from anyone else.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
        if ($user['id'] != $this->request->params['pass'][0]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ACL is probably the way to go: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
```

in beforeFilter() tells cake that anyone is allowed to view the index & view actions irrespective of whether or not they are signed in or not.

You must perform your tests in isAuthorized() and test there whether the action can be performed by the user or not. Return true if the action ($this->action) can be performed by the current user, or false if they can't.

```
public isAuthorized($user = null) {

  switch($this->action) {

    case "index":
    case "view":

      if ($user['role'] == 'admin') {

        return true;

      }

      break;

    case "edit":
    case "delete":

      if ($user['id'] == $this->request->params['pass'][0]) {
        return true;
      }   

      break;

   }

   return false;

}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can get current User from Session

to render some partial element in your View (*.ctp)

```
<?php
$user = $this->session->read('Auth.User')

if(!$user){
    echo $this->element('logmein');
}else{
    echo $this->element('logmeout')
?>
<h2>Here is member section</h2>
<?php
//... do some thing for member
}
?>
```